# Dedicating PhD thesis to my Dad who recently passed away

Tags: phd, thesis, acknowledgement, dedication

I lost my Dad while waiting for the examiners reports of my thesis. In my final copy I would like to include a dedication page to him (in addition to the general acknowledgements page), but I'm not really sure what to say. I know I would like something really short, but more than "I dedicate this thesis to my Dad."

I was thinking including something about how I know how proud he was even though he won't be around to see me graduate. Or perhaps referencing how I hope my dedication to my field in science stays as strong as his dedication to his own field (engineering).

I would appreciate any suggestions or examples of dedications as I haven't managed to find too much online and I'm lost for words.

Comment: Your own suggestion is fine.

Comment: If a friend asked for me advice about this situation, I would advise them to write their honest feelings as best they could express them in their own words, without worrying about whether it is exactly the right thing to say as a dedication.

Comment: I think you'll feel best about it if you come up with something on your own, rather than using examples from people who don't know your Dad. If you're lost for words, just a couple of them is going to be just as meaningful.

Comment: OP - thanks everyone, I'll try to come up with something in my own words to use.

Comment: @user125368 Perhaps ask close friends to comment on the words you find.

Comment: Do as you feel. I did more or less what you propose. A page after the standard acknowledgement with a lyrics from a song (even in my dialect) and a short sentence saying "she couldn't see this work finished. This theses is dedicated to her". Just to say that I felt free to express myself, at least in that regard. Also I ask a friend as suggested above.

Comment: My condolences! Just do what you think is right! Your suggestion seems fine since it is coming from your heart.

Comment: Sorry for your loss, op. Don't worry about the dedication page: this is _your page_, write as you fell, as long as it is not disrespectful to the member of the examination committee, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 8):

I had a dedication page in my PhD thesis, to my recently deceased grandparents. I kept it short, with a line that basically translates to:

"To my grandparents, in loving memory."

The things you suggest to include and to reference will make it more personal, and more appropriate for you. And that is all that matters: write it such that it represents well how you feel.

Answer (score 8):

I started my Ph.D. a few years after my father passed away. I dedicated the thesis to him. I wrote, "To my father who never saw this adventure" (something like this when translated).

Like all who commented, I would say keep it short, keep it personal. Grief makes it difficult to find words. Actually, looking back at my thesis and this dedication bring back memories of him. I guess that's what this dedication page is for: yourself.